# Python Regular expression to remove blanks before and after a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm buildin a tiny python program and I can't find the correct regex. Let me explain myself:

I have the next string

```
bar = '    Type of network         : Infrastructure'
```

And with de following code:

```
foo = re.findall(r'(\w+(\s\w+)+)\s+:\s+(\w+)', bar)
print(foo)
```

I obtain:

```
[('Type of network', ' network', 'Infrastructure')]
```

And I would like:

```
[('Type of network', 'Infrastructure')]
```

I know that I could do that splitting the string by ':' and trimming blanks, but I prefer the regex.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following one?

```
foo = re.findall(r'\s*(.*?)(?:\s*:\s*)(.+)(?<!\s)', bar)
```

It also handles strings like:

```
'    Type of network         : Infra structure  '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine, but can you explain me the last part (?<!\s)  ? I don't recognize (?<

Comment: @ellgon: (?<!regex) - this is so called 'negative lookbehind' pattern. Take a closer look at: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind)

Answer (score 2):

Just another solution without using regex `[ x.strip() for x in bar.split(':')]`

Output: `['Type of network', 'Infrastructure']`

Comment: I would definitely go for this solution.

Comment: Hi ikaros45. It's there any reason for you to choose this method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use non-capturing brackets:

```
(\w+(?:\s\w+)+)\s+:\s+(\w+)
```